# How to store value of var in Spring message tag in java script function?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-messaging

> I have one function that is returning some kind of string string is
>   not static it is dynamic

```
<code of script function>
var error_msg = sendPinAjaxResponse("some url");
```

> And i am using spring message tag to change language

```
 $("#error_div").html('<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="static string" />')
```

> when i pass static string it works fine
>
> but i want to store dynamic value of var, now i am using the var
>   'error_msg'

```
 $("#error_div").html('<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code= error_msg />')
```

> its giving an exception  on jsp page

```
 quote symbol expected
```

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
$("#error_div").html('<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="' + error_msg + '"/>')
```